# FutureBuilder data not getting updated on button click

Tags: php, flutter, dart

So starting by giving a brief of the issue. I have defined a function to get data from my api and the function is:

```
Future<void> getProductDetailsData(params) async {
    if (_isNetworkAvail) {
      await apiBaseHelper
          .getAPICall(getProductData, params)
          .then((getdata) async => {
                if (getdata.containsKey('data'))
                  {
                    productDataList = (getdata['data']['items'] as List)
                        .map((data) => ProductModel.fromJson(data))
                        .toList(),
                    tempProductDataList.addAll(productDataList),
                  }
              });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isNetworkAvail = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

and the params I have given is `Future<void> myData = getProductDetailsData({'id': widget.dealerId.toString()});`
and then I have used `myData` in the `future` of the FutureBuilder.

now I have defined a MultiSelectDialogField and on its onConfirm I want to change the params so that I can get a particular data as per the given params. So for this I have done this

```
onConfirm: (results) {
                setState(() {
                  myData = getProductDetailsData({
                    'id': widget.dealerId.toString(),
                    'categoryId': "23",
                  });
                });
              }
```

But the issue is that the FutureBuilder is not getting updated and only showing data with params as `{'id': widget.dealerId.toString()}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use either `await` or `.then` to get value from future. Inside your `.then` you need to call `setState`.

```dart
Future<void> getProductDetailsData(params) async {
  if (_isNetworkAvail) {
    apiBaseHelper
   .getAPICall(getProductData, params)
        .then((getdata) async => {
              if (getdata.containsKey('data'))
                {
                  productDataList = (getdata['data']['items'] as List)
                      .map((data) => ProductModel.fromJson(data))
                      .toList(),
                  tempProductDataList.addAll(productDataList),
                }
                setState(() {}); //here
            });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _isNetworkAvail = false;
    });
  }
}
```

better

```dart
Future<void> getProductDetailsData(params) async {
  if (_isNetworkAvail) {
   final getdata =  await apiBaseHelper
   .getAPICall(getProductData, params); 
     if (getdata.containsKey('data'))
        {
       ....
                }
    setState(() {});
            
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _isNetworkAvail = false;
    });
  }
```

also you can just use `await` and call setState on next line. Also you can use FutureBuilder.

Comment: Brother tried your solution but still it is showing the same data with the params as `{'id': widget.dealerId.toString()}`

Comment: seems you are using variable, you can convert to method or reassign like `myData = getProductDetailsData({'id': widget.dealerId.toString()});`

Comment: sure will try and let you know

Comment: Still the issue isn't fixed reassigned like `myData = getProductDetailsData({'id': widget.dealerId.toString()});` as suggested but issue is still there

Comment: did you call setState after reassign  `myData `

Comment: Yes I did, but I have tried another way and that way solved my issue. What I did is that on onConfirm I just updated the params only and did not pass the whole function